# Can server code be in a separate project for IBM Worklight project?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I was wondering if its possible to have server code placed into a separate project and still be able to invoke and access the code from my IBM Worklight project. Or does all server code(including custom java classes) need to be within the same project.

Comment: AFAIK it must be in the same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server code ( including all the custom java classes ) needs to be with in the same project.
Because while building WAR file java files are also needs to be builded. ( you can rename the war file to zip file and see the java class files)

What you actually wants to try?